# clear autocomplete text after selected in flutter?

Tags: flutter, autocomplete

i have created an autocomplete text field:

```
                Autocomplete(
                          optionsBuilder: (TextEditingValue textEditingValue){
                            if (textEditingValue.text.isEmpty){
                              return const Iterable<String>.empty();
                            }
                            else{
                              return autoCompleteData.where((word) => word.toLowerCase()
                                  .contains(textEditingValue.text.toLowerCase())
                              );
                            }
                          },
                          onSelected: (value) {
                            print("this is the value $value");
                            setState((){
                              selected=value.toString();
                            });
                            
                          }
                      ),
```

which suggest me some value when i type by a json file.
**Now what i want whenever i select the value it must clear the box .**

Comment: Clear the box means? Could you give us more details? Like you want clear the word or dismiss the suggestion box when you select a word/text.

Answer (score 11):

In order to achieve this we should have access to text edit controller, so you could do something similar to access to text edit controller inside Autocomplete

```
late TextEditingController textEditingController;
        Autocomplete(
          optionsBuilder: (TextEditingValue textEditingValue) {
            if (textEditingValue.text.isEmpty) {
              return const Iterable<String>.empty();
            } else {
              return _allSpecialitySkills
                  .where((word) => word.name.toLowerCase().contains(textEditingValue.text.toLowerCase()));
            }
          },
          onSelected: (value) {
            print("this is the value $value");
            textEditingController.text = "";
          },
          fieldViewBuilder: (BuildContext context, TextEditingController fieldTextEditingController,
              FocusNode fieldFocusNode, VoidCallback onFieldSubmitted) {
            textEditingController = fieldTextEditingController;
            return TextField(
              controller: fieldTextEditingController,
              focusNode: fieldFocusNode,
              style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            );
          },
        )
```

Find the simple project that I did to achieve the above,

```
List<String> countries = <String>[
  "Africa",
  "Antarctica",
  "Asia",
  "Australia",
  "Europe",
  "North America",
  "South America",
  "Srilanka",
  "India",
  "China",
  "Japan",
  "Koria",
  "Thai",
];

class AutoCompleteExample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _AutoCompleteExampleState();
}

class _AutoCompleteExampleState extends State<AutoCompleteExample> {
  late TextEditingController textEditingController;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Autocomplete(
      optionsBuilder: (TextEditingValue textEditingValue) {
        if (textEditingValue.text.isEmpty) {
          return const Iterable<String>.empty();
        } else {
          return countries.where((word) => word.toLowerCase().startsWith(textEditingValue.text.toLowerCase()));
        }
      },
      onSelected: (value) {
        print("this is the value $value");
        textEditingController.text = "";
      },
      fieldViewBuilder: (BuildContext context, TextEditingController fieldTextEditingController,
          FocusNode fieldFocusNode, VoidCallback onFieldSubmitted) {
        textEditingController = fieldTextEditingController;
        return TextField(
          controller: fieldTextEditingController,
          focusNode: fieldFocusNode,
          style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think the solution is to add TextEditingController and FocusNode to your RawAutoComplete:

RawAutocomplete(
textEditingController: textEC ,
focusNode: focusNode1,optionsBuilder:....

Answer (score 0):

#### Using Key

For my case i reseting the widget using key (recreate the widget without last state), when key change the widget will rebuild here's the main code:

```
setState(() {
    valueKey= UniqueKey();
});
```

here's what implementation looks like with **formbuilder** package

```
class _AutoCompleteState<T extends Object> extends State<_AutoComplete<T>> {
          var valueKey = UniqueKey();
          @override
          Widget build(final BuildContext context) {
            return Autocomplete<T>(
              key: valueKey,
              optionsBuilder: widget.options,
              onSelected: (final selectedString) {
                FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
              },
              fieldViewBuilder: (
                final context,
                final controller,
                final focusNode,
                final onEditingComplete,
              ) {
                return FormBuilderTextField(
                  onReset: () {
                    setState(() {
                      valueKey= UniqueKey();
                    });
                  },
                  focusNode: focusNode,
                  controller: controller,
                  autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                  onEditingComplete: onEditingComplete,
                  name: widget.name,
                );
              },
            );
          }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

i can't tell you a precise solution because you are not sharing all the code but
you should probably just re-initialize textEditingValue to empty string

```
setState((){
selected=value.toString();
//call a method that set textEditingValue = ""
        });
```